# Parallel compression C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, compression

Is it possible to optimize this code using `Parallel.Foreach` or something?

```
using (var zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(OpenWriteArchive()))
{
    zipStream.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Level9;    
    foreach (var document in docuemnts)
    {
        zipStream.PutNextEntry(GetZipEntryName(type));    
        using (var targetStream = new MemoryStream()) // document stream
        {
            DocumentHelper.SaveDocument(document.Value, targetStream, type);    
            targetStream.Position = 0; targetStream.CopyTo(zipStream);
        }    
        GC.Collect();
    };
}
```

The problem is DotNetZip's and SharpZipLib's `ZipOutputStream` doesn't support position changing or seeking.

Writing to zip stream from multiple threads leads to error. It's also impossible to accumulate result streams into 
ConcurrentStack beacuse application can work with 1000+ documents and should to compress and save streams into the cloud
on the fly.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Do you *have* to zip all the files into one and the same archive?

Comment: Yes, all entries (documents) should be into one and the same archive

Comment: If the ZipOutputStream *did* support seeking and position changing and you managed to implement a marshalling system that would allow multiple threads to write in it simultaneously, it would still be your bottleneck.
A marshalling system like that would probably also cause more overhead than you could gain from parallel processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by using of `ProducerConsumerQueue` (Producer-Consumer pattern).

```
using (var queue = new ProducerConsumerQueue<byte[]>(HandlerDelegate))
{
    Parallel.ForEach(documents, document =>
    {
        using (var documentStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // saving document here ...

            queue.EnqueueTask(documentStream.ToArray());
        }
    });
}

protected void HandlerDelegate(byte[] content)
{
    ZipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf");

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(content))
    {
        stream.Position = 0; stream.CopyTo(ZipOutputStream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to decleare zipstream inside parallel foreach, like:

```
Parallel.ForEach(docuemnts, (document) =>
            {
                using (var zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(OpenWriteArchive()))
                {
                    zipStream.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Level9;
                    zipStream.PutNextEntry(GetZipEntryName(type));
                    using (var targetStream = new MemoryStream()) // document stream
                    {
                        DocumentHelper.SaveDocument(document.Value, targetStream, type);
                        targetStream.Position = 0; targetStream.CopyTo(zipStream);
                    }
                    GC.Collect();
                }
            });
```

Bye!

Comment: All documents should be in the same archive